# Como colocar quebra de linha no textview direto do xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

queria colocar de forma mais organizada esse texto sem precisar criar varios textview , e tive a ideia de utilizar quebra de linha .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o caractere de escape `\n`:

```
android:text="linha1\nlinha2\nlinha3"
```

Comment: tem algum exemplo quando o texto é dinamico pra quebrar a linha?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar tags HTML em um texto do seu `strings.html`

segue um exemplo:

**strings.html**

```
 <string name="minha_receita_1"> <![CDATA[ <ul> <li>1 caneca ou bule</li> <li>1 garrafa térmica</li> <li>1 colher (sopa)</li> <li> 1 coador de café</li> </ul> ]]> </string>
```

O conteúdo `html` deverá estar entre `<![CDATA[ ]]>`

No java faça o seguinte:

```
     TextView textHtml = TextView.class.cast(convertView.findViewById(R.id.receita));
    final Spanned textoEmHtml = Html.fromHtml( getContext().getString(R.string.minha_receita_1));
    textHtml.setText(textoEmHtml);
```