# Como exibir elementos HTML em um TextView do Android?

Tags: java, android, api

Estou desenvolvendo uma Api que retorna alguns textos, porém esses textos tem *tag* HTML, seja negrito `<b>` ou linha `<P>` gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor forma de imprimir isso em um `TextView`, ou se eu devo arrumar o texto antes de enviar para a API.

Lembrando que eu tenho o controle da API e do cliente

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191586/como-colocar-quebra-de-linha-no-textview-direto-do-xml/191595#191595

Comment: Relacionado: [Como formatar o texto num TextView](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166114/2541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...]gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor forma de imprimir isso[...]

Quanto a melhor forma, isso vai de sua necessidade. Não tem nenhum problema em definir um texto HTML dentro do seu `TextView`. Seria basicamente desta forma:

```
String htmlJsonText = "<h2>Titulo</h2><br><p>Descrição here</p>"; 
textViewHTML.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlJsonText));
```

Veja mais detalhes na documentação [sobre a classe HTML](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html).